# Text in autocompletetextview to be highlighted or deleted when the user clicks on the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, textview, autocompletetextview

When a user click on an ACTV and finds what he is searching for, the only reason for him to select the ACTV again is to search for something else. I am looking for a way where when user has made a search in the ACTV and the search text is in the ACTV field (suggestions menu is closed) when the user clicks on the ACTV to write again, the current text to be highlighted or deleted on the click that opens the keyboard for the user to start typing their new search.

Comment: just adding
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
in the xml but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AutoCompleteTextView search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search);

search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do what ever you want
                              (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search).setText(""); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ok! This is good! I just added search.setText(""); on the inside and it works like a charm. Thanks dude. Appreciate your help. Can you just eddit your answer and add what I added so that more people can see it.

Answer (score 2):

For highlighting:

`android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` (xml attribute)

or

`autoCompleteTextView.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);` (programmatically)

Comment: For Editing the entire filed using BS